# Graph API - Read outlook Emails without signature

Tags: machine-learning, outlook, nlp, microsoft-graph-api

I have a Machine learning model that can classify emails, I'm using GraphAPI to read emails but, model performance is not up to the mark since I'm unable to remove the signature from email for training.

Is there any way to read emails from outlook without email signature?

Comment: No, the email's signature is also considered as a body data and you could find that data inside the body's content property. Please raise a feature request in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) so that the Product team may develop it in future.

Comment: Mailgun have open sourced their library for parsing out signatures that may help you work around the issue. https://www.mailgun.com/blog/open-sourcing-our-email-signature-parsing-library/

Comment: Moving this to answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, the email's signature is also considered as a body data and you could find that data inside the body's content property. Please raise a feature request in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) so that the Microsoft Graph product team may develop it in future.